# Multiple elements in Xml Schema

Tags: xsd

I have a schema, where there are 3 elements and these 3 elements still have more sub elements. Lets name 1st element as Header, 2nd one as record, 2rd one as footer.

There is one occurence of header, multiple occurences of record and one occurence of footer again.

so the input to schema looks like

```
header
record..
record..
...
..
footer
```

now my problem is . my schema is defined like this

```
<xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="HEADER"> 
<xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="Record"> 
<xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="FOOTER">
```

when a file (with a header 2 records and footer)is parsed through this schema. the parser recognizes  recognizes the header and both the records and gives an exception after recognizing the 2nd record and doesn't give the footer. How do we define max and min occurs when there are 2 or more elements and middle element has unbounded as max occurs

EDIT:

thanks for the replies. This is my xsd file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<xs:schema xmlns:NS="sample.xsd" xmlns="sample.xsd" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="sample.xsd" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="PTRO">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>


   <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="HEADER">
   <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
    <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="header_sub_element">
                <xs:simpleType>
               </xs:simpleType>
              </xs:element>
   </xs:sequence>
          </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>


        <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="Record">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="Record_sub_element">
                <xs:simpleType>
                  <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                    <xs:maxLength value="11" />
                  </xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpleType>
              </xs:element>
             </xs:sequence>
          </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
       <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="FOOTER">
   <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
    <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="footer_sub_element">
                <xs:simpleType>
                  <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
          <xs:maxLength value="9" />
                   </xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpleType>
              </xs:element>
   </xs:sequence>
          </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
</xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
 </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

@ marc_s the problem is when an input file (.txt file) which contains a header, 2 records, footer is parsed using this schema, the parser recognizes header and records...and after this it gives an exception since it doesn't recognize the footer. The max occurs of Record is unbounded. Does this have something to do with the exception ??

Comment: Can you show us your real schema, and a sample XML that causes this problem?? I'm not quite clear from your question what the issue is...

Answer (score 0):

You have to use < sequence >< /sequence > instead of the < all >< /all > or < choice >< /choice >.

That should solve the problem.